# Javascript array.forEach(function) executing function twice as many times as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, sleep

I have a html file with a single button on it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    <body>
<p>Click the button to list all the items in the array.</p>

<button onclick = "numbers.forEach(myFunction)" >Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>     
</html>
```

I also have the Javascript file containing the `onclick` function for the `.forEach` method.
When the button is clicked the I'd like to go through an array, looping through each instance of element in the array.

For every element in this array, I'd like to print out its index and value with a timer afterward that waits a second to display the next permutation.

```
demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
var numbers = [];

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

numbers.push(random);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  numbers.push(random);
  demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + "numbers[" + index + "]: " + item + "<br>"; 
  //demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + "<br>" //add magic spacing between permutation
  sleep(100);
  //switch to this and see how slow?
  //sleep(1000);
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like the result to show when the user clicks the button is:

```
numbers[0] = 4
//waits a second and adds a <br> here to separate
numbers[0] = 4
numbers[1] = 2
//waits a second and adds a <br> here
numbers[0] = 4
numbers[1] = 2
numbers[2] = 3
```

and so on.

Currently the code outputs at least twice as many elements, and the sleep() seems to be lasting way longer than it should.

Comment: Please don't try to add a `sleep` function. Instead learn how to do asyc calls through something like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.    Also consider using `console.log` to track your code as it runs.  And since you are changing the array `numbers` while doing a `forEach` you are asking for problems.  And doing a `forEach` within the DOM element `onclick` attribute is not the best way to go. Have `onclick` call a function and do the `forEach` in that function.

Comment: @Intervalia I was having problems with the amount of times its intervaling, so instead of using the 'setTimeout' or 'setInterval' I created a 'sleep()' to test it.

Comment: @Jamin I made a mistake in my answer. Please read the new updated one. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the hideous `sleep` function. You are using `myFunction` as the callback of `forEach`, and in `myFunction`, you are pushing new elements to `numbers` which is the same array you are calling `forEach` on.

`forEach` won't call the callback on the newly pushed items while still looping the array. But by the end of the loop, the items in the array will be doubled. As according to MDN:

> The range of elements processed by `forEach()` is set before the first invocation of `callback`. Elements that are appended to the array after the call to `forEach()` begins will not be visited by `callback`.

If the array contains `N` elements, then when a click happens, `N` elements will be shown, and `myFunction` will push `N` other elements, and when the next click happen `2N` elements will be shown this time, ...

So after each click, the elements in the array will be doubled.